# Angular 6: Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Observable<Response>'

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

Property 'map' does not exist on type. I am Trying to import 'rxjs' module different way but it does not work.

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';

list(){
    return this.http.get(endpoint)
        .map(responce=>responce.json())
        .catch(this.handleError)
  }
```

Comment: Btw you should also migrate to `HttpClient`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Since it is Angular 6, you're using RxJS in its 6th version.

This is the RxJS 6 way for what you want to do:

```
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

list(){
    return this.http.get(endpoint)
        .pipe(
            map(responce=>responce.json()),
            catchError(this.handleError)
        )
  }
```

In angular 6 you don't have to call `.json()` because it's done implicitly so this sample is wrong and you don't need `map` at all, but it's just to show you the equivalent for `.map()` in RxJS 6

Answer (score -1):

Open your terminal and just command this

```
npm install --save rxjs-compat
```

or

```
npm install --save rxjs-compat@6
```

or

```
npm i rxjs-compat --save-dev
```

I home your problem will be fixed.